# How to create select all check box in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have create a list view and inside listview template I have multiple check box.

I have a select all check box on before the list view.

Select all and deselect all works fine.

How can uncheck “SelectAll” check box if I uncheck any of the check box present inside list view.

Comment: add an event handler to the individual checkboxes that updates the SelectAll  whenever one of the list items is changed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add new field and bind it to the property `IsChecked` of CheckBox.

And we can add event handler to the individual CheckBoxes of your `ListView`, then we can update the binded property of the CheckBox(`IsCheckAll`).

I created a demo and achieved this function.

You can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
 public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public bool IsUnCheckedOneItem { get; set; } = false;


    // add property `IsCheckAll` for the  `Select all` checkbox
    private bool _isCheckAll;
    public bool IsCheckAll
    {
        get => _isCheckAll;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isCheckAll, value);

            //update all the items

            if (!IsUnCheckedOneItem) 
            {
              updateAllItems(IsCheckAll);

              IsUnCheckedOneItem = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateAllItems(bool  ischecked)
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.IsChecked = ischecked;
        }
    }

    public ICommand CheckAllCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand UpdateThisItemCommand { get; set; }


    public MyViewModel() { 
     Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Items.Add( new Item { NumType = "S" , LocationCode = "0001"});
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "S", LocationCode = "0001" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "M", LocationCode = "0002" });
        Items.Add(new Item { NumType = "L", LocationCode = "0003" });


        UpdateThisItemCommand = new Command<Item>(checkboxcommand);

    }

    private void checkboxcommand(Item obj)
    {
        if (obj!= null)
        {
            if (!obj.IsChecked  )
            {

                // you also need to add some other logic codes here

                if (IsCheckAll && !CheckAllMethod()) {
                    IsUnCheckedOneItem = true;

                    IsCheckAll = false;

                }
            }
            else if (obj.IsChecked && CheckAllMethod()) {
                IsCheckAll = true;
            }
        }
         // here
        IsUnCheckedOneItem = false;
    }

    public bool CheckAllMethod()
    {

        bool ischeckedAll = true;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            if (!item.IsChecked)
            {
                ischeckedAll = false;
            }

        }

        return ischeckedAll;
    }

    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**Item.cs**

```
 public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ // IsChecked for the checkbox of Item in listview
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isChecked, value);
        }
    }

    public string NumType { get; set; }

    public string LocationCode { get; set; }

    public string Barcode { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PickingAdjustementDate { get; set; }


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext> 
    <xamlistviewapp:MyViewModel></xamlistviewapp:MyViewModel>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical"
                  Spacing="25"
                  Padding="30,0"
                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                 >

    <Label  Text="select all items"/>
    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckAll}"   >

    </CheckBox>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="listview"   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  >
            
            <ListView.Header>TheHeader</ListView.Header>
            
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding NumType}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LocationCode}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                        <CheckBox  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.UpdateThisItemCommand, Source={x:Reference listview}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    EventName="CheckedChanged" />
                            </CheckBox.Behaviors>

                        </CheckBox>

                    </Grid>


                </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```