# How can I multi-select items in the model using picker in xamarin or otherwise?

Tags: c#, xamarin, checkbox, multi-select, picker

xaml.cs page:

```
public partial class TalimatGorevEkle : ContentPage
    {
        TalimatGorevModelmobil Model;
        
        public TalimatGorevEkle() { 

            InitializeComponent();
            var kullanicilist = Methodlar.GorevliListeGetir(Sabitler.Token);
           
            
            KullaniciSec.ItemsSource = kullanicilist.GorevliListe;  //picker'da listelenecek kişiler

            
        }
    }
```

.xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="OzelKalem.Views.ListeContentViews.TalimatGorevEkle">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
              
               <Grid>
                   <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Padding="8">
                       <Label Text="Görev Başlığı:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14"></Label>
                       <Entry x:Name="talimatAdi" Placeholder="Görev Başlığı Giriniz" HeightRequest="60" ></Entry>
                       <Label Text="Görev Adı:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14" ></Label>
                       <Entry x:Name="talimatGörevAdi" Placeholder="Görev Adı Giriniz" HeightRequest="60" ></Entry>
                       <Label Text= "Görevin Son Tarihini Seçiniz:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14"></Label>
                       <DatePicker Format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" x:Name="gorevSonTarih" TextColor="Black" ></DatePicker>
                       <Picker x:Name="KullaniciSec" Title="Kullanıcı seçiniz." ItemsSource="{Binding GorevliListeModel}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding GorevliKullaniciAdi}"></Picker>
                       <Button x:Name="SaveCourseButton" Clicked="GorevEkle" Command="{Binding}" Text="Kaydet" BackgroundColor="LightGray" TextColor="#FF7F24" Margin="3" />
                       
                   </StackLayout>


               </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I have a list in xamarin I have it displayed in picker. But I want it to be multiple selectable. How can I write for it?
How should I select it as checkbox or over the picker?
[image]

Comment: Use a CollectionView with multi select enabled.  A Picker can’t do this

Comment: Do you have a resource you can recommend?I am very new to xamarin. I have listed the list from the service using model. Then I need to save the selected ones in multiple way @Jason

Comment: yes, read the [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection) docs

Comment: very thanks.When I write this, so when I succeed, I will add it here and share it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , for multi-select items, you can use
[Multiple selection of CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#multiple-selection) to achieve this.

And you can check the official sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/).

Of course, you can also add `CheckBox` to each item of the `ListView` to achieve this.

There is a similar thread here, you can check it here: [How to create select all check box in xamarin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75414248/how-to-create-select-all-check-box-in-xamarin-form/75444657#75444657).

Comment: This is how I did it using Collection View. I'll add it below as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have used collection view but I need to set the list of selected users to TaskList in my View model. Actually, I need to send all the data entered in this form to the Service using the View model.selected user
How can I assign a list to a variable?

TalimatGorevEkle.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using OzelKalem.Models;
using Plugin.Toasts;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace OzelKalem.Views.ListeContentViews
{
    public partial class TalimatGorevEkle : ContentPage
    {
        TalimatGorevModelmobil Model;
        
        public TalimatGorevEkle() { 

            InitializeComponent();
            var kullanicilist = Methodlar.GorevliListeGetir(Sabitler.Token);
        


            CollectionView collectionView = new CollectionView
            {
                SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple
            };
            collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "GorevliListeModel");
            collectionView.SelectionChanged += OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged;
            collectionlist.ItemsSource = kullanicilist.GorevliListe;
            collectionlist.ScrollTo(kullanicilist.GorevliListe);
            



        }
        void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
          
        
            var previous = e.PreviousSelection;
            var current = e.CurrentSelection;
          
        }

        private void GorevEkle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var talimat = talimatAdi.Text;
            var talimatGorev = talimatGörevAdi.Text;
            var gorevSonTariih = gorevSonTarih.Date;
            GorevliListeModel items = collectionlist.SelectedItems as GorevliListeModel;
            

           



            }
        }

    }
```

TalimatGorevEkle.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="OzelKalem.Views.ListeContentViews.TalimatGorevEkle">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
              
               <Grid>
                   <StackLayout  Grid.Row="0" Padding="8">
                       <Label Text="Görev Başlığı:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14"></Label>
                       <Entry x:Name="talimatAdi" Placeholder="Görev Başlığı Giriniz" HeightRequest="60" ></Entry>
                       <Label Text="Görev Adı:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14" ></Label>
                       <Entry x:Name="talimatGörevAdi" Placeholder="Görev Adı Giriniz" HeightRequest="60" ></Entry>
                       <Label Text= "Görevin Son Tarihini Seçiniz:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14"></Label>
                       <DatePicker Format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" x:Name="gorevSonTarih" TextColor="Black" ></DatePicker>

                       <!-- <Picker x:Name="KullaniciSec" Title="Kullanıcı seçiniz." ItemsSource="{Binding GorevliListeModel}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding GorevliKullaniciAdi}"></Picker>!-->
                       <Label Text="Kullanıcı Seçiniz:" TextColor="#FF7F24" FontSize="14" ></Label>
                       <CollectionView x:Name="collectionlist"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding GorevliListeModel}"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding GorevliKullaniciAdi}" Margin="10" HeightRequest="150">
             <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                 <DataTemplate >
                     <StackLayout >

                         <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal" >
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                         <Label Text="{Binding GorevliKullaniciAdi}" FontSize="14" Padding="5"></Label>
                     </StackLayout>

                 </DataTemplate>

             </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        
    </CollectionView>
                       <Button x:Name="SaveCourseButton" Clicked="GorevEkle" Command="{Binding}" Text="Kaydet" BackgroundColor="LightGray" TextColor="#FF7F24" Margin="3" />
                 
                   </StackLayout>


               </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class TalimatGorevModelmobil
    {
        public string TalimatBaslik { get; set; }
        public string TalimatGorevAdi { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int TalimatID { get; set; }
        public int Durum { get; set; }
        public DateTime EklenmeTarihi { get; set; }
        public int IslemKulID { get; set; }
        public List<GorevliListeModel> GorevliListe { get; set; }
        public DateTime SonTarih { get; set; }
        public int ServisBaglantiDID { get; set; }

    }
    public class GorevliListeModel
    {
        public string GorevliKullaniciAdi { get; set; }
        public string GorevliID { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]